# How far down the ancestry line do you call a person your "cousin"?

Tags: word-usage

Should individuals on your family tree, 8 or 9 generations, still be called cousins? After aunts & uncles, should you call all individuals on a family tree "cousins"?

Comment: While it can be fun to figure out that someone was, say, your third cousin 6 times removed, in practical usage, you just call them "people on your family tree" and/or "ancestors".

Comment: In the USA (can't speak for elsewhere) _cousin_ means either someone who is in fact related to ego by being a child* of siblings of ego's parents; or someone related to ego in any way that's not immediate family; or someone who is a close friend and spends a lot of time with ego's family (if they're significantly older than ego, the terms _uncle_ and _aunt_ are used for the close friend relation, instead of _cousin_).

Comment: This may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin

Comment: You can call anyone with a common ancestor your cousin but 'distant cousin' is used when the relationship is pretty remote.

Comment: There's a young woman at work with the same last name as mine, but since that name (Clark) is an occupational name, chances are good that we aren't related at all.  I still call her "cousin" or "cuz" when speaking to her.  Like "Good morning, cousin!"  I think it annoys her slightly, which adds to the fun.

Comment: @Martha Not if your mother was a Southern Lady, DAR and DOC, you don't.

Comment: Biblically Jesus was 42 generation from Abraham and was still considered Abraham's seed. I consider everyone from my great, great, grandfather(Slave) my relatives and all generations after me from all his descendents.

Answer (score 5):

Enthusiasts who like to pin matters down precisely follow these rules:

- Everybody from whom you are directly descended is your *X-parent/-father/-mother*, where *X* is ∅ in your parents' generation and *grand-*, *great-grand-*, *great-great-grand* and so forth in previous generations, with reduplication of *great* after that at each previous generation.
- Siblings of X-parents are similarly *X-uncles* and *X-aunts*.
- Everybody directly descended from you is your *X-child/-son/-daughter*, where *X* is ∅ in your children's generation and *grand-*, *great-grand-*, *great-great-grand-* and so forth in following generation, with reduplication of *great* after that at each following generation.
- Direct descendants of your own siblings are similarly your *X-nephews/-nieces*.
- Everybody else on your family tree is a *cousin* of some sort: *m*th cousin *n* times removed, where *m* is the number of generations you must track back above your own to reach an 'X-parent', a common ancestor, you share with the person in question, and *n* is the difference (absolute) between a) the number of generations between you and the common ancestor and b) the number of generations between the person in question and the common ancestor.

Comment: That's a great answer, but you leave out grand-aunts and grand-uncles.  Your grandparents siblings are these.  Your great grandparents siblings are likewise great grand-aunts and -uncldes.  And so on.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist 'doh:} I'll fix it.

Comment: The last bit (n times removed) is perhaps more clearly explained as the _difference_ between your generations: if you're both the same generation (genealogically, not chronologically), then you're simply mth cousins, but if one of you is x generations from the common ancestor, and the other is y generations away, and x is less than y, then you're xth cousins y minus x times removed. So my first cousin's kids are technically my first cousins once removed.

Comment: I think there are still a few typos in your post. You duplicate "great", not "grand" for extra generations. And the cousin part is a bit unclear about removal (as JPmiaou noted while I was typing this).

Comment: @Blckknght Quite so about grand/great ... fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good relationship calculator that you might find of interest in determining who is a cousin.

[Relatedness Calculator](http://apps.nolanlawson.com/relatedness-calculator/)

Fun all around!